AWS alb with ingress-nginx fails healthchecks
I want a single load balancer (alb) that direct traffic to internal nginx-ingress that load balances traffic to internal services in the cluster.
I have followed many examples (ex_1) and I have reached to a point where the alb heathchecks to the nodes fail.
When I connect to a nginx-ingress-controller pod and execute a /healthz to the pod IP, it works, but fails when I try to the service
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: infra
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: "ip"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /healthz
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: 30343
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: "200,404"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: ***
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: ssl-redirect
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: ingress-nginx-controller
                port:
                  number: 80
---
---
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: infra
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: ingress-nginx
      reconcileStrategy: ChartVersion
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: ingress-nginx
      version: 4.10.1
  interval: 1m0s
  values:
    controller:
      publishService:
        enabled: false
      replicaCount: 4
      config:
        use-forwarded-headers: "true"
        use-proxy-protocol: "true"
      service:
        externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
        type: NodePort
        targetPorts:
          http: http
          https: http

What am I missing?
